# How can I clean silicone mastic stains from a bath-tub and tiles?

Tags: bathroom, cleaning, bathtub, silicone

I was redoing the silicone dilation around the bath-tub, using the silicone mastic from a tube. Unfortunately, I stained the tub and a tile with silicone. You cannot see it really, but they got quite slippery, which is obviously frowned upon.

I failed to clean them with abrasive cleaner, and trying to "clod it" by hands didn't help either (this works with acrylic mastic and I supposed the silicone one would be the same, is it not, though). How can I clean it off so that the surface becomes less slippery, as it was before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on dried silicone and is pretty non-toxic

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, I've had success with an eraser:

[image]

It won't damage tile, but results depend on how porous/grippy the tile surface is.

[Amazon sells them](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00006IFAR), so should any local Office Supply or School Supply store.

Comment: The tile is quite "rough" hence not slippery itself an probably quite porous. Can you please provide a link to a reasonable e-shop that sells this item? Thanks